Was Jesus the 'Good Master ' or just 'a Master ' to the rich young man in Mtt 19:16-17?
We read in Mtt 19:16-17( KJV):

And, behold, one came and said unto him, Good Master, what good thing shall I do, that I may have eternal life? And he said unto him, Why callest thou me good? there is none good but one, that is, God: but if thou wilt enter into life, keep the commandments.

But the ESV uses a different phraseology :

And behold, a man came up to him, saying, “Teacher, what good deed must I do to have eternal life?” And he said to him, “Why do you ask me about what is good? There is only one who is good. If you would enter life, keep the commandments.

ESV omits the 'Good' emphatically used  in the ' Good Master ' salutation of KJV. While in KJV Jesus puts a counter-question on  WHO is Good, ESV's counter-question is on WHAT is Good. How do Bible scholars explain that difference in the phraseology of KJV Vs ESV in the presentation of  Mtt 19:16-17 ?
PS : A few questions have already been asked on BHE on the topic. I am looking for some new perspectives. Please bear with me.

The 'good' accompanied with 'master' was added in at a later time for unknown reasons and by unknown persons as far as I can tell. Looking back at the Greek, Nestle-Aland Greek New Testament and in the United Bible Societie's third edition, 'good' is not found, but merely master or teacher. Perhaps the Latin Vulgate should be looked at a little closer to try to identify when the addition happened.

Thanks, Biff. Both the young man's salutation and Jesus quick question go together. WHO is good is more revant vis -a-vis WHAT is good in the context. The salutation is something like addressing the audience as "Gentlemen..."

Let us take these two verses separately.
Matt 19:16
There is only one material difference between the two Greek texts of Matt 19:16 as follows:
NA28, UBS5, W&H, NIVGNT, THGNT, etc

Καὶ ἰδοὺ εἷς προσελθὼν αὐτῷ εἶπεν Διδάσκαλε, τί ἀγαθὸν ποιήσω ... =
and behold, one having come to Him said, "Teacher, what good shall I do
...

Byzantine text:

Καὶ ἰδού, εἷς προσελθὼν εἶπεν αὐτῷ Διδάσκαλε ἀγαθε, τί ἀγαθὸν ποιήσω
... = and behold, one having come, said to Him, "Good
teacher, what good shall I do ...

Note that the Byzantine text adds an extra "good".  However, why the KJV translates "teacher" as "master" (a quite different word in the Greek) is another of the KJV inconsistencies.
Matt 19:17
NA28, UBS5, W&H, NIVGNT, THGNT, etc

ὁ δὲ εἶπεν αὐτῷ Τί με ἐρωτᾷς περὶ τοῦ ἀγαθοῦ; εἷς ἐστιν ὁ ἀγαθός ... =
but the one said to Him, "Why ask me about what is good?  One is good
...

Byzantine text:

Ὁ δὲ εἴπεν αὐτῷ, Tί με λέγεις ἀγαθόν; Οὐδεὶς ἀγαθός, εἰ μὴ εἷς, ὁ
θεός. ... = but the one said to Him, "Why call me good?  No one [is]
good but one God. ...

Again, the main difference between these is simply the underlying Greek text.  For details about the various supporting manuscripts, see UBS5.

'Master' relates to a 'School Master', commonly called a 'Teacher'. It is an acceptable translation of διδασκαλε αγαθε.

@NigelJ - that is a modern use.  Most other places, the same word is translated "teacher".

My take on the Master translation is that it's a good example of why we need to respect the KJV as an excellent historical translation, but move on to the best modern versions. Master doesn't mean teacher, which is why in the comment above Nigel needed to add "school". My guess is that 400 years ago "Master" meant teacher and was the right translation (It comes from the Latin Magister which had "teacher" as one of its meanings.) But the English language has moved on since then.

Yes there is a subtle difference between Teacher and Master. A master trains disciples; teacher trains students. In ancient times, the Orient had residential schools where disciples would stay with their master and even do daily chores for him. The master would train each student according to the capacity and capability of each. Some disciples would turn out to be perfect match for the master once they complete the training .
Lk 6:40( KJV):The disciple is not above his master: but every one that is perfect shall be as

The disciple is not above his master: but every one that is perfect shall be as his master ( Lk 6:40 KJV)

I think, Byzantine version is more logical, for otherwise, in the NA28, UBS5, W&H, NIVGNT, THGNT, etc. there is a clumsy and awkward breach of logic: the boy asks what "good thing" to perform, and the Lord answers him not on this question, but that there is "the only one who is good", that is, God. But is not it so, that doing the commandments of God, who solely is good, is to do good? I guess, the main idea is that the Lord reprimands the boy, but in the non-Byzantine version the point of reprimanding is lost altogether.
Now, in Byzantine version it is clear for what reason does the Lord reprimand the boy: for calling Him "good"; because, if, as the Lord says, only one is good, that is to say, the God, then the boy commits a blunder of calling Him so, if he does not believe that He is God, which the kid indeed did not believe. However, in the immediate sequel the Lord teaches him that He is indeed addressable by the title "good", for He is God, because God is perfect and the Principle who makes us, the imperfect ones, also perfect, and here the Lord says that He is exactly this Principle of perfect-making ("sell everything, follow Me and I will make you perfect").
Byzantine thus is the better version both logically and theologically. Even if the initial version was the other one (which I do not believe to be the case at all! See for example Anne's excellent study on this BH site link: How to explain the differences in Matthew 19:16-17 translations? ), a scribe who changed it in the Byzantine way, was truly inspired.

Thanks, Levan, for the insightful answer, especially the way you have connected 'good' to 'perfect'. That leads to yet another question: Did Jesus say 'perfect ' or 'complete ' . Many oriental languages do not have an original word for perfect. In stead, they use the words  'whole ' and 'complete'  as is seen in Jesus words on the Cross.
